# Ключевые ценности сообщества Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, справка

Ключевые ценности сообщества — это руководящие принципы и эвристики, которыми мы пользуемся, принимая более сложные нетривиальные решения. Они дают основу для понимания правил нашего сообщества. Обычно, ключевые ценности передаются из уст в уста, от более опытных участников к новым, когда первые реагируют на действия последних на сайте.

Давайте вместе посмотрим на наши ключевые ценности, обсудим их и занесем в справочный центр. Это должно помочь нам поддерживать культуру сообщества в долгосрочной перспективе и повысить эффективность обучения новых участников стандартам сообщества.

Существуют три ключевые ценности, которые являются общими для всех международных сообществ Stack Overflow:

## 1. Люди в первую очередь

- **Отношения между участниками в сообществе — то, как мы относимся друг к другу — ключевой критерий успеха**. Наша первоочередная цель — создание и поддержка самого сообщества. Все остальное — следствие.
- **Любое взаимодействие на сайте начинается с взаимного уважения к коллегам**, вне зависимости от обстоятельств, репутации, знаний или чего–либо еще.
- В нашем сообществе **каждый [чувствует себя в безопасности в окружении единомышленников](/conduct), когда задает или отвечает на вопрос**.

## 2. Чем больше *хороших* знаний о программировании на русском языке, тем лучше!

- **Stack Overflow — это библиотека готовых решений прикладных задач**, собранных в формате проблема (вопрос) — решения (ответы) в сжатом виде без ненужных деталей. Только «сигнал», никакого «шума».
- **Вопрос и ответы пишутся один раз, читаются — миллионы раз**. Все содержимое сайта оптимизируется для чтения, для разработчиков пришедших на сайт из поиска.
- **Наличие полезных для сообщества знаний на сайте — важно, то как они были созданы — вторично**. Мы приветствуем любые способы создания *полезных* знаний на сайте, кроме плагиата. В том числе:

  - [публикация лучших практик, в формате вопроса со своим ответом](/help/self-answer);
  - [переводы вопросов с других языков](/help/translate-from-english);
  - общие вопросы, поддерживаемые сообществом;

  и, конечно, [ваши текущие проблемы](/help/how-to-ask), на которые мы вместе найдем решения.

## 3. Вместе на благо сообщества

- **Stack Overflow — сайт коллективного накопления [знаний по программированию](/help/on-topic)**. Сайт существует благодаря сотрудничеству множества активных участников, таких же как и вы.
- **Вместе мы создаем полезные знания для всего русскоязычного сообщества**. Любой русскоговорящий разработчик, столкнувшись с технической проблемой, может использовать ответы с сайта совершенно бесплатно.
- **Само сообщество — это результат совместной работы**. Мы вместе определяем будущее нашего сайта и сообщества на Мете.

---

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие другие ключевые ценности видите вы? Какие ценности, из описанных выше, на ваш взгляд, не являются ключевыми? Какие изменения вы бы внесли в текст выше, перед добавлением в справку?

Буду рад услышать ваши мысли, идеи и предложения! Давайте вместе сделаем наш сайт ещё лучше.

**Обновление**

Обновил текст согласно замечаниям и рекомендациям сообщества. Ребята, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Остались ли еще недочеты? Планирую в понедельник с утра добавить справку.

**Обновление 2**

Большое спасибо всем, кто принял участие в обсуждении. Новая страница справочного центра находится по адресу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values. Пожалуйста, напишите мне, если вы видите какую–либо ошибку.

Comment: Думаю, фраза **а не одному великому человеку** в 3-м пункте лишняя

Comment: Тут ничего не сказанно про системное администрирование. Грядёт разделение? Может я чего-то не знаю просто.

Comment: @L.F.C.  Нет, разделения не будет :) Тематика сайта описана на [специальной странице в справочном центре](/help/on-topic)

Comment: Это хорошо, если честно Николас.Правда, очень часто в комментариях сталкиваюсь с рьяно защищающими идею разделения. И я могу их понять в каком-то смысле, но когда всё вместе, намного удобнее.

Comment: @L.F.C.: Нет, не лишняя. У неё есть конкретные адресаты.

Comment: @VladD да, я понял юмор этой записи :) Моё мнение, ей там не место, но это лишь моё мнение

Comment: @L.F.C.: Она хорошо показывает ключевые ценности администрации.

Comment: @L.F.C. Чтобы исключить конспирологическую полемику вокруг этого термина, если я верно его понимаю, то фраза относится к основателям проекта (по большей части Stack Overflow на английском). Вероятно, ее можно как–то расширить. Смысл остается при этом тот же: *Stack Overflow — это то, что мы создаем вместе, всем сообществом*.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Вы сами писали текст? Если да, почему у вас лишь _предположения_ («если я верно его понимаю») о его смысле? Если нет, укажите, что это перевод, а не авторский текст, и проставьте ссылку на источник.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky добавил ответ с предложением, как раз-таки чтоб меньше полемики было.

Comment: @VladD Смотрите, мы все разные. Мы можем понимать один термин по разному. Я выше описал, как его понимаю я и с каким смыслом он был использован в вопросе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: В таком случае формулировка плохая, и её имеет смысл уточнить, чтобы она не вызывала разночтений.

Comment: @VladD Возможно! Пожалуйста, поясните вашу идею в ответе к вопросу: как на ваш взгляд стоит изменить формулировку и почему.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Лень. Это ж вы допустили плохую формулировку, вам и исправлять.

Comment: `...читаются — миллионы раз` — несколько переоценённое значение... максимальное количество просмотров, что я нашёл на ruSO порядка 300-с-чем-то тысяч...

Comment: А давайте стараться писать на нормальном русском языке, не засоряя его иностранными словами, не вошедшими в широкий обиход. Тем более, когда есть нормальные русские слова, которые намного точнее выражают мысль. Зачем писать "коллаборация", когда есть нормальное русское слово "сотрудничество"? "Коллаборация" к тому же вызывает нехорошие ассоциации с коллаборационистами, которые с фашистами сотрудничали.

Comment: @m.vokhm  Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли у вас еще синонимы? На мой взгляд, «коллаборация» шире, чем «сотрудничество», это скорее «совместная работа».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Не знаю, почему вам так кажется. Я посмотрел сейчас 4 разных словаря, и все приводят значения 1) Сотрудничество; 2) Пособничество врагам, оккупантам (напр. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collaboration). Ну если вам не нравится "сотрудничество", так и напишите -- "совместная работа", хотя "сотрудничество", на мой взгляд, точнее выражает суть StackOverflow. "Совместная работа" скорее подразумевает работу в одной фирме, в одном помещении и т. п.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что фразу `Сайт существует благодаря коллаборации множества активных участников, таких же как и вы, а не труду одного великого человека.` лучше изменить. Даже если вы что то другое имели ввиду, то тут у любого на сайте, кто в курсе драм, не будет сомнений о ком тут идет речь. На фоне дружелюбного посыла остальной части текста - эта часть выглядит больше как издевка, а не ценность.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо! Подскажите, как бы вы переписали эту фразу?

Comment: да просто вырезал бы лишнее `Сайт существует благодаря коллаборации множества активных участников`

Comment: @tym32167 Посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновление. Есть ли у вас замечания?

Comment: @VladD Поправил замечание по поводу «одного человека». Подскажите, есть ли еще что–то, что бы вы хотели изменить?

Comment: Теперь норм, спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Всё хорошо написано, но пару моментов вызвали определенные вопросы.
В конце 2-го пункта:

> и, конечно, *ваши текущие проблемы*, на которые мы вместе найдем решения.

Мне кажется момент с текущими проблемами надо уточнить, а то он слишком размыт.

В 3-м пункте:

> Stack Overflow — сайт коллективного накопления знаний по программированию. Сайт существует благодаря коллаборации множества активных участников, таких же как и вы, а не труду одного великого человека.

Последнее предложение, лучше изменить на:

> Stack Overflow — сайт коллективного накопления знаний по программированию. Сайт существует благодаря коллаборации множества активных участников, таких же как и вы.

Последняя фраза явно лишняя, о чём я указал в комментариях выше.

Ну и если мы всё-таки не обходим стороной сетевое администрирование можно на такой вариант:

> Stack Overflow — сайт коллективного накопления знаний по программированию и сетевому администрированию. Сайт существует благодаря коллаборации множества активных участников, таких же как и вы.

Comment: Спасибо! Поясните, пожалуйста, почему вы считаете последнюю лишней?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Как минимум из-за всех этих (периодических) войн в чате, которые ведуться последний год. Эта фраза может перекручиваться кем угодно и как угодно, и в последствии может быть использована в нехорошем контексте. Лучше убрать от греха подальше. Я понимаю, что много чего прилетает с основного сайта (но у них там свои проблемы, а  у нас свои), но мы же всё-таки многие вещи меняем на ruSO, так почему бы и тут не подправить?

Comment: «*момент с текущими проблемами надо уточнить*» — подскажите, как бы вы уточнили?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky и, конечно, *ваши текущие проблемы, относящиеся к тематике сайта*, на которые мы вместе найдем решения. Хотя бы так.

Comment: Спасибо! На мой взгляд, это не требуется, из контекста ясно, что речь идет про сайт. Иначе надо к каждому пункту добавить это пояснение =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky На здоровье! Чем смог, тем помог! :)))

Comment: Думаю, стоит заменить «коллаборацию» на «слаженную работу» или «совместную работу». Предложение станет более понятным (да и с коллаборационизмом нехороших ассоциаций не будет). // @NicolasChabanovsky

Comment: @Arhad Спасибо! «совместная работа» — звучит отлично! Кстати, ниже предлагают «кооперацию». Что скажите?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, `Что скажете?` - тоже вариант. Но конкретный выбор, как по мне, надо делать уже всем миром.

Comment: @Arhad Выше еще упоминают «сотрудничество», что, на мой взгляд, наиболее точно выражает идею!

Comment: @Arhad, L.F.C. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновление. Есть ли у вас замечания? Администрирование обыграл добавлением ссылки на [справку по темктие сайта](/help/on-topic), так как у нас тем куда больше, все не впишешь, будет громоздко.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в таком варианте - отлично!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, замечаний больше нет, всё хорошо выглядит.

Answer (score 3):

> "Внутригрупповые отношения"

Может просто "Человеческие отношения"? А то так сразу и не скажешь о чём это :) Либо `Отношения - то, как мы, участники, относимся друг к другу - ключевой критерий успеха.`

> каждый чувствует себя в безопасности и «принятым»

Что значит "принятым"? Может быть "каждый чувствует себя в безопасности и может рассчитывать быть понятым"?

> в кристаллизированном виде с минимальным шумом и максимальным сигналом

На счёт шума всё понятно, но с сигналом нужно прояснить. Может "в сжатом виде без ненужных деталей"?

> Сайт существует благодаря коллаборации множества активных участников

Поддерживаю высказавшихся ранее о "коллаборации" - не comme il faut. Да и не нужно уточнять на счёт "активности - пассивности". Может быть "Сайт существует благодаря кооперации множества участников"?

> а не труду одного великого человека

Неужели на этот счёт у кого-то сомнения? Может быть лучше убрать полностью?

Comment: Фраза «каждый чувствует себя в безопасности» — это тоже неоднозначно. Имеется в виду, что каким бы плохим не был вопрос, его не заминусуют и автору не поставят на вид? Вряд ли.

Comment: @VladD не знаю, конечно, какой смысл в это вкладывался, но скорее всего эта некая дежурная фраза, по типу свободы вероисповедания и т.п..

Comment: Ну, если это дежурная фраза, тогда ее можно смело в ключевые ценности не включать

Comment: @VladD согласен :)

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Очень интересные замечания.  «*Внутригрупповые*» — основная мысль фразы в том, что *отношения между участниками* для нас прежде всего. Быть «принятым» и «понятым», на мой взгляд, разные вещи. На английском языке это «be a welcoming place». Подскажите, как бы вы на русском языке выразили это понятие?

Comment: «_в сжатом виде без ненужных деталей_» — очень близко, но не до конца раскрывает исходную фразу. Соотношение «сигнал / шум» показывает сколько на сайте находится полезной информации к бесполезной с позиции читающего. «в сжатом виде без ненужных деталей» можно лишь вместо «кристаллизированном». Подскажите, как бы вы вторую часть предложения выразили?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky на счёт "отношений между участниками"... В принципе можно вообще оставить только "отношения", т.к. далее следует более чем развёрнутой объяснение. "Принятый-понятый" - ну не говорят-же так на-русском - "быть принятым". И "да", Вы правы в том, что это разные вещи, но ведь и "принимают" куда-то или в что-то. Тогда нужно уточнить куда "принимается" человек задавая вопрос. На счёт кристаллов и сигналов: я исходил из того, что "В сжатом виде" ~ "в кристаллизованном виде", а "без нужных деталей" ~ "с минимальным шумом и максимальным сигналом", т.е. всё указано во фразе.

Comment: @XelaNimed Посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновление. Есть ли у вас замечания?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как я понял наличие "сигнала" с "шумом" принципиально? Ну а если так, то на мой взгляд, понятно. Лишь бы всё заявленное соответствовало действительности.

Comment: @XelaNimed Да, на мой взгляд это важно.

Answer (score 2):

Замените слово коллаборации на сотрудничество. Вы же на русском языке говорите.

Насчет того, что каждый чувствует себя в безопасности - может стоит заменить на то, что вы к этому стремитесь. Я вообще не понимаю, как можно чувствовать себя в безопасности, когда любой может тебе поставить минус просто так, а твои ответы исправляются без твоего согласия. Так что очевидно чувствуют себя в безопасности не все, поэтому данное заявление не является правдивым.

Если у вас здесь есть какие то меры против превращения сообщества в стадную диктатуру посредственностей (которые конечно же считают себя самыми умными и терпимыми потому что друг другу это внушают), из которой изгоняются все оригинально и просто инакомыслящие, хотелось бы в вашей декларации об этих мерах услышать.

И, кстати, если вы цените интеллект и оригинальность мышления в данной декларации самое место об этом заявить. Вы об этом не заявили, может забыли, а может не цените - остается неопределенность. Может быть стоит внести ясность по этому вопросу.

Comment: Нет, интеллект и оригинальность мышления не находятся в ценностях. В ценностях здесь скорее толерантность и поддержка неумелых новичков в стиле печально известного Linux CoC.

Comment: Как жаль, что нельзя переводить репу в плюсы... (издержки идеи равенства -))

Comment: На мой взгляд, в фразе «больше *хороших* знаний» заложен и «интеллект», сайт ведь именно за тем и нужен, чтобы собирать знания. Пожалуйста, поясните подробно про «*из которой изгоняются все оригинально и просто инакомыслящие*». Что это такое и вообще к чему? Где вы видели такое? Как ответ на вопрос по программированию может быть «инакомыслящим»? Я не видел, чтобы «оригинальные» ответы или их авторов «изгоняли». Скорее они получали много голосов за.

Comment: Что касается «*превращения сообщества в стадную диктатуру*» — этот сайт модерируется сообществом. Если вы хотите видеть модераторами исключительно назначаемых сотрудниками компании участников, которые единолично решают что к чему, хотите видеть сайт, где нельзя улучшать чужие сообщения, возможно, Stack Overflow не подходящий выбор. В наших ценностях заложено обратное — мы создаем свободную базу знаний *вместе*, в том числе каждый может принять участие в модерации содержимого сайта.

Comment: @VladD а как проверяется интеллект ??? Мерило интеллекта не подскажете ?? Как считать интелект в пятнистых косулях , выведете  пожалуйста формулу перевода размерности "интеллекта в пятнистых косуль".    Мне мама говорит, что я очень умный и что я умнее всех, оцените пожалуйста мой интеллект :3

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky♦, знания это о содержимом, а интеллект - это о людях-участниках. И этим людям у вас посвящены отдельные пункты. Один из самых известных примеров - бан (имеено бан, т. к. это слово на английском означает "анафема, отлучение") Джордано Бруно и принуждение Галилея к отречению от геоцентрической системы. История науки и Библия говорят о том, что большинство неправо, а истина не определяется голосованием. В программировании множество воззрений и мнений, имеющих своих приверженцев, между которыми ведутся споры, зачастую похожие на религиозные.

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky♦, на данном конкретном сайте этих примеров я еще не видел, рано судить, т.к. я здесь еще мало бывал. Если увижу - обязательно напишу. Возможно, это даже легко смоделировать - если я начну говорить правильные вещи, расходящиеся с мнением большинства. Боюсь только, что из-за кучи минусов я уже не смогу сюда ничего написать.

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky, что касается 'улучшения', то раз уж по сообщениям даются оценки участникам и под этими сообщениями стоит их подпись, редактирование их выглядит не очень то правильным. Тут же не абстрактные данные собираются, а еще идет мерянием рейтингом с 'наказаниями' и 'поощрениями'. Мне вы вообще не хотелось видеть модерирования сообщений за исключением случаев нарушения приличий (удаление в этом случае, а не редактирование), причем эти правила должны быть прописаны максимально конкретно.

Comment: @timob256: Ну примерно так же, как оценивать «уважение к коллегам» или там «качество ответа».

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky Насчет примеров  - вот, пожалуйста. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/969586/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0 Конкретный вопрос по Java и теории программирования закрыт из-за несоответствия тематике сайта. У вас тут сайт не по программированию? Или Java в тематику не входит? Нет, просто мнению толпы не соответствует.

Comment: @Eugene вообще то, ваш вопрос должен быть закрыт как порождающий бесконечные прения и дискуссии. А редактирование - тут редактирование используется именно для стилистического изменения вопроса, чтобы другие люди могли нормально понять этот вопрос. Например, выделить код, или вынести главную мысль.

Comment: Боюсь, что Николас не увидел ваше сообщение, поэтому его призову я: @NicolasChabanovsky вам там выше написали ответы ^^

Comment: @Eugene К сожалению, я не вижу связи между закрытием указанного вами вопроса и ключевыми ценностями сообщества. Если вы хотите обсудить закрытие вопроса (например, если вы считаете, что его закрыли по ошибке), пожалуйста, задайте отдельный вопрос, чтобы любой участник сообщества видел его и мог предложить свое решение.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦, это пример подавления толпой, которого вы до сих пор не видели. Вот я вам его и показываю. Могу показать еще несколько.